# Azure Pipelines: git diff-tree shows empty string

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, git-diff-tree

I am trying to get all the committed files on an Azure Build Pipeline.
This is the yaml script I'm using:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - swagger_dev
  paths:
    include:
      - swagger_dev/swaggers/*.yaml

variables:
  CLIENT_CREDENTIALS: $(ClientCredentials)

steps:
  - powershell: |
      echo "$(Build.SourceVersion)"
      echo "$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --diff-filter=d --name-only -r $(Build.SourceVersion))"
```

When I commit one or more files, the Pipeline correctly echoes the Build.SourceVersion but then echoes an empty output for the git command:
[pipeline log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kDIP.png)

How is that possible?
I am currently on a branch called swagger_dev and the committed files are in the directory swagger_dev/swaggers. Maybe I should add those informations to the diff-tree command?

Comment: Try: $(git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only) - This works for me, but I am not using any build version.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @DillyB
Unfortunately it does not work, I get this error:
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

Comment: The fact that there's no previous commit (`HEAD~` is an `unknown revision` means "there is no previous commit") explains the problem: you have a *shallow clone*, as directed by your CI system's default settings. Adjust those defaults, if that's possible, to make sure you have at least a depth-2 clone.

Comment: Once you've fixed that, remember that `git diff-tree` should generally get two commits or trees (as in @DillyB's answer). Given just one commit ID, Git will use its parent(s).

Comment: Thank you so much torek, I think this can be the right solution! I am trying to understand how I can avoid the shallow clone on Azure Devops, do you have any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git diff-tree command requires at least depth 2 to get the changed files.

The cause of the issue can be related to the fetch depth of the Pipeline repo.

By default, the Shallow fetch of the pipeline repo is  1 by default.

You can try to set the **fetchDepth** to **0** or **>2** in YAML Pipeline.

For example:

```
steps:
    - checkout: self
      fetchDepth: 0
```

Or you can navigate to **YAML Pipeline -> ... -> Triggers -> YAML -> Get sources -> Shallow fetch**.  You can unselect the option.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The bash task which I am using is to check the name of the tfvars file.

```
- bash: |
              PATH_FILTER="folder1/**/*"
              CHANGED_FILES=$(git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only -- `find . -name "*.auto.tfvars"`)
              MATCH_COUNT=0
              MATCH_FILE=""
              FILE_PATH=""
              FILE_NAME=""

              echo "Checking for file changes..."
              for FILE in $CHANGED_FILES
              do
                if [[ $FILE == *$PATH_FILTER* ]]; then
                  MATCH_FILE=${FILE}
                  MATCH_PATH="$(dirname ${FILE})"
                  FILE_NAME="$(basename ${FILE})"
                  echo "MATCH:  ${FILE} changed"
                  MATCH_COUNT=$(($MATCH_COUNT+1))
                else
                  echo "IGNORE: ${FILE} changed"
                fi
              done
```

Comment: Using bash I get a similar message:
fatal: bad revision 'HEAD~'